# post_save error Message' has no attribute

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm trying to use signals **post_save** for the first time. I have read the documents, but still need some advice.

I'm trying to update my model field called 'charge'.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Message)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if not sender.charge:
        sender(charge=sender.length(sender))
        sender.save()
```

However, this gives the error Message' has no attribute 'charge', but charge does exist within message!

Comment: Note that, because `sender` is the `Message` class itself, rather than an instance, your 4th line instantiates a new Message, then throws the reference away, while the 5th line calls `.save()` on the class, which will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sender` here is the `Message` class itself, not the instance that's being saved. The actual instance is passed as the keyword argument `instance`. Also, with `post_save`, if you're not careful, you'll get yourself in an infinite loop. Better to use `pre_save`.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Message)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if not instance.charge:
        instance.charge = instance.length()
        # No need to save, as we're slipping the value in 
        # before we hit the database.
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, I also tried (sender, instance=None,  **kwargs): that that works.